# How to create open api documentation in .yaml format with maven?

Tags: java, maven

I am building a rest api and part of the requirement is that we write documentation according to the open api specification. I am using (http://editor.swagger.io) to do this, and I find it irritating, and way less affective than creating normal javadoc. Is there a maven plugin, or something that can build documentation from comments in .yaml or .json format according to the open api specification? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for that maven library https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/

It can automatically generate specifications in html